# I cannot mimic sniffed urb interruption using libusb for Ruby

Tags: ruby, usb, interrupt, hid, libusb

## Sniffed URB_INTERRUPTions

I sniffed communication between some application (SoundLab) and device (sonometer with usb). I found a packet responsible for returning current state:

```
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.1.2]
    USBPcap pseudoheader length: 27
    IRP ID: 0xffff858d126f4a60
    IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)
    URB Function: URB_FUNCTION_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER (0x0009)
    IRP information: 0x00, Direction: FDO -> PDO
        0000 000. = Reserved: 0x00
        .... ...0 = Direction: FDO -> PDO (0x0)
    URB bus id: 1
    Device address: 1
    Endpoint: 0x02, Direction: OUT
        0... .... = Direction: OUT (0)
        .... 0010 = Endpoint number: 2
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Packet Data Length: 8
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
Leftover Capture Data: b331eb4d00000000
```

It is sent by application to endpoint number 2 (out), and then device sends urb interruption with data to endpoint number 1 (in):

```
USB URB
    [Source: 1.1.1]
    [Destination: host]
    USBPcap pseudoheader length: 27
    IRP ID: 0xffff858d10207af0
    IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)
    URB Function: URB_FUNCTION_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER (0x0009)
    IRP information: 0x01, Direction: PDO -> FDO
        0000 000. = Reserved: 0x00
        .... ...1 = Direction: PDO -> FDO (0x1)
    URB bus id: 1
    Device address: 1
    Endpoint: 0x81, Direction: IN
        1... .... = Direction: IN (1)
        .... 0001 = Endpoint number: 1
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Packet Data Length: 8
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
Leftover Capture Data: 01a9009b90ddc0ff
```

## Attempt to mimic interruptions with libusb

Now I want to mimic this in Linux, using [libusb](https://github.com/larskanis/libusb). I wrote this code where I can test different interruptions.

```rb
require 'libusb'
require 'pry'

vendor_id = 0x64bd
product_id = 0x74e3

module Messages
  GET_STATE = ['b331eb4d00000000'].pack('H*')
end

usb = LIBUSB::Context.new
device = usb.devices(idVendor: vendor_id, idProduct: product_id).first

dev_handle = device.open

if dev_handle.kernel_driver_active?(0)
  dev_handle.detach_kernel_driver(0)
end

dev_handle.claim_interface(0)

binding.pry

dev_handle.release_interface(0)
dev_handle.close
```

Then I run this in `pry` console:

```rb
dev_handle.interrupt_transfer(endpoint: 2, dataOut: Messages::GET_STATE)
```

And it returns `8`. That is not what I expected.

## URB_INTERRUPTions I see when I run my code

```
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.6.2]
    URB id: 0xffff8802142fecc0
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x02, Direction: OUT
    Device: 6
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: present (0)
    URB sec: 1559130571
    URB usec: 534195
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 8
    Data length [bytes]: 8
    [Response in: 126]
    [bInterfaceClass: HID (0x03)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 8
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
Leftover Capture Data: b331eb4d00000000
```

```
USB URB
    [Source: 1.6.2]
    [Destination: host]
    URB id: 0xffff8802142fecc0
    URB type: URB_COMPLETE ('C')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x02, Direction: OUT
    Device: 6
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('>')
    URB sec: 1559130571
    URB usec: 534846
    URB status: Success (0)
    URB length [bytes]: 8
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Request in: 125]
    [Time from request: 0.000651000 seconds]
    [bInterfaceClass: HID (0x03)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 8
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
```

## Summary

In result I get URB_INTERRUPTions that are much different from what I saw on Windows. On Windows I had urb_interrupt to 2 (out) endpoint with data requesting state of device. Then device was sending urb_interrupt to 1 (in) endpoint with current state encoded in capture data. How can I mimic this with `LIBUSB::DevHandle#interrupt_transfer`? Here is documentation of this method: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/libusb/LIBUSB/DevHandle#interrupt_transfer-instance_method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried meld-ing the expected versus received USB output that you posted, and the main thing that stood out to me was that your 'actual' USB protocol captures showed one URB_INTERRUPT in (marked by the 'direction' field). In your 'actual' USB traffic dump, it looks like you have 2 URB_INTERRUPT outs.

I'm not an expert in the USB protocol (I came across this question while myself stumbling around for help reverse-engineering a USB driver as well), but from what I can tell, to get a URB_INTERRUPT *'in'* (which is what you have in the expected output), you have to change the endpoint address to 0x82 instead of just 2.

This answer talks about this further: https://superuser.com/a/876773/618124

> USB endpoints 0x00-0x7F are on the host, and the endpoints 0x80-0xFF
> are on the device (I think).

Give that shot and see if it works?